# SharePoint Online - Update User Profile Properties via CSOM App

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-apps

I have a console application where I am updating SharePoint Online user profile properties via CSOM.  When I do it via the following code below (using a username and password), it works just fine.

```
private static void UpdateUserProfileProperties()
{
    var userAccountName = "i:0#.f|membership|myAccounName@mySite.com";
    var siteUrl = "https://mySite-admin.sharepoint.com";
    var myUserName = "myUserName";
    var myPassword = "myPassword";
    var secureStringPassword = new SecureString();
    myPassword.ToList().ForEach(c => secureStringPassword.AppendChar(c));

    using (var context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
    {
        var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(myUserName, secureStringPassword);
        context.Credentials = credentials;

        var peopleManager = new PeopleManager(context);
        var personProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor(userAccountName);

        context.Load(personProperties, p => p.AccountName, p => p.UserProfileProperties);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

Now, I have created an app in SharePoint (via the AppRegNew.aspx page). I granted the app tenant-level permissions (via the AppInv.aspx page) and the following Permission Request XML:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl"/>
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Now, I am using the clientID/clientSecret to authenticate instead of a username and password - using this code:

```
public static void UpdateUserProfileProperties2()
{
    var userAccountName = "i:0#.f|membership|myAccounName@mySite.com";
    var siteUrl = "https://mySite-admin.sharepoint.com";
    var siteUri = new Uri(siteUrl);
    var siteRealm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(siteUri);
    var siteToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, siteUri.Authority, siteRealm).AccessToken;

    using (var context = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(siteUri.ToString(), siteToken))
    {
        var peopleManager = new PeopleManager(context);
        var personProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor(userAccountName);

        context.Load(personProperties, p => p.AccountName, p => p.UserProfileProperties);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

I can get the token and the context just fine.  When the line `context.ExecuteQuery();` executes, I get the following exception:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

The app clientID/clientSecret works for all sorts of other site-based operations.  Is it possible to load the user properties in the admin site via a clientID/clientSecret?  If so, can you provide an example?  How can I grant the app the appropriate permissions?

Comment: was it a problem of app not having access to user profiles thru appmanifest.xml?

Comment: What libraries you have imported for `PeopleManager`, I am getting error in using `PeopleManager`

Answer (score 0):

If you gave your add-in the correct permissions:

1. http://sharepoint/social/core
2. http://sharepoint/social/tenant

then the only thing that can be wrong is the user permissions. SharePoint code is executed with permissions which are the intersection of the add-in permissions and the current user permissions.